# Printing input color with firefox with css

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to print out a table that has inputs with colors. these colors are assigned by the users to each input. this  means each table is differnet each time someone edits it. I found a work around with webkit browsers but firefox does not work of coarse!!!!

```
@media print {
[id^="output26"] {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

This works fine on chrome and safari

Any ideas? Is playing around with the css a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the warning for this [propertys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) documentation.

Let me quote it:

> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use      it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.